# Node.js Mongoose trouble

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to build my first REST-api but I keep getting this error with the mongoose module.

The error message looks like this:

```
Josephs-MacBook-Pro:rest joseph$ node server
API is running on port 3000

        /Users/joseph/Documents/Atom-files/rest/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:228
                process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                                    ^
        Error
            at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/joseph/Documents/Atom-files/rest/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:42:24)
            at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
            at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
            at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
            at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
            at require (module.js:384:17)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/joseph/Documents/Atom-files/rest/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/index.js:2:17)
            at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
            at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

My server.js file looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/rest_test');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));



app.listen(3000);
console.log('API is running on port 3000');
```

And finally my api.js file looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/products', function(req,res){
  res.send('api is working');

});


module.exports = router;
```

I'm (obviously) new to developing in Node.js, and do not know why this error occurs. I know that `process.nextTick` has something to do with the node-loop, but I have no idea why the error would occur just as I start my application.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is precisely the error mongoose will give you if you don't have mongoDB running on your localhost. Assuming you have mongodb installed already you can run it in a terminal with `mongod`, but it might be preferable in the long run to have it running with launchctl. To do that, follow these steps:

Install homebrew if you haven't already (http://brew.sh/)

Then use it to install mongodb

```
brew doctor
brew update
brew install mongodb
```

Configure mongoDB to run via launchctl:

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
pushd ~/Library/LaunchAgents
cp `brew --prefix`/Cellar/mongodb/**/*.mongodb.plist .
launchctl load -w *.mongodb.plist
popd
```

And with that you should be good to go, no need to run `mongod` again after a reboot.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful! One more question, if you don't mind? The script works after this, but it always make the terminal stall, so that I have to press CTRL + C every time and shut down the script, which is very annoying.. Do you know what the reason for this might be?

Comment: Feel free to ask this as a separate question :)

Comment: it is because it cannot connect to a host?